# What bird makes this sound?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

It sounds like some kind of crow but not really. Here is my recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TsKFUugot8&feature=youtu.be#t=06s

This bird always wakes me up at 04:00 and this started in late June. I live in a village in Hungary.

I really need to know and don't know where to ask.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mention 1) where you heard this 2) what time of day 3) what period of the year.

Comment: The portion of the bird's voice is very short. maybe less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be confirmed but it sounds like a pelican.

[image]